# Rqt plugin: qt_gui_main() found no plugin

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to implement my own rqt plugin with C++. It consist of a QGraphicsView with few QGraphicsItems.
I did it like in rqt_image_view, basically by copying and adjusting the content of CMakeList.txt, package.xml, plugin.xml, setup.py.

However it is build without any errors when I try to launch it I get a message:
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "agent_gui"

I have no idea what can I do wrong here. I have included PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in source file of my class inheriting from rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin, added appropriate export in plugin.xml. Just like in rqt_image_view plugin and the tutorial.

I use ROS groovy and catkin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Filip

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95091/rqt-plugin:-qt_gui_main()-found-no-plugin/) by [robodude](https://answers.ros.org/users/8221/robodude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I solved the problem in other way.

I had to change library path in plugin.xml from scr to lib :

Now everything works.

---

Originally posted by [robodude](https://answers.ros.org/users/8221/robodude/) with karma: 36 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Applying the changes described in this answer solved the issue for me: http://answers.ros.org/question/91231/rqt-plugin-not-listedfound-in-list-returned-by-rqt-list-plugins/?answer=91386#post-id-91386

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2